# How to host Laravel 5.2 in GoDaddy shared hosting without SSH?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have developed a web application in Laravel 5.2. I want to host it in Godaddy Shared hosting in a sub folder, because I have other projects there for different domains.

I'm not sure if I explained it clearly, this is what I'm trying to achieve.

I have put all my Laravel files in a sub folder like (www.mylaravelapp.com/test).

Now I can access the application with this URL "www.mylaravelapp.com/test/public".

```
public_html/
  some_domain_folder/  
  www.mylaravelapp.com/
     test/
        app/
        bootstrap/
        config/
        database/
        public/
        etc..
```

How can I access this with a URL like "www.mylaravelapp.com/"?

How to solve security issues too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to allow hosting two sites in GoDaddy's cpanel. If you have access then you have to do the following things.

1. Goto this [link](https://in.godaddy.com/help/adding-addon-domains-to-your-cpanel-shared-hosting-account-8877), it is a guide to add add-on domains, and add your domain (**www.mylaravelapp.com**) as add-on domain.
2. It will create another folder in your root directory like `mylaravelapp`.
3. Then copy the contents of the `test` directory into the `mylaravelapp` directory.
4. Now the structure is like this:

Folders

```
   |`-- public_html
     |-- some_domain_folder
     |`-- mylaravelapp
        |`-- app
        |`-- config
        |`-- bootstrap
        |`-- database
        |`-- public
```

Now go to the public folder and move `index.php` and `.htaccess` to `mylaravelapp`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you @Vishal Patel.. but my problem is not with domain routing. I just   now find the problem and solved it.

Comment: This is what is did  with the index.php and need to be update this line **require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';** as **require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php** And  this line **$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';** to be **$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';**  like this. be course my index file is in now root directory

Comment: i had a problem with the **cipher** after update the config/app.php

Comment: I had problem with the **config/app.php**  the **.env** files values does not get by app.php file so, I have manually copy and past the appropriate values.now my app working fine. And now my all public folder files are in root directory